# Vuetify unselect v-chip

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I read Vuetify's documentation and forums but could not find how to unselect a selected `v-chip`:

```
    <v-chip-group
       column
       active-class=""
    >
       <v-chip 
           class="chip"
           v-for="genre in genres"
           :key="genre" 
           @click="updateGenres(genre)">
           {{ genre }}
       </v-chip>
    </v-chip-group>
```

How can I unselect it by clicking again on the chip itself or elsewhere on the window?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/chip-groups) `v-chip-group` has boolean prop with by the name `Mandatory` which always

> Forces a value to always be selected (if available).

which is `false` by default so change your `v-chip-group` to something like this

```
<v-chip-group
     :mandatory="mandatory"
     :column="column"
     active-class="primary--text">
     <!--Your chips goes here-->
```

An change your props property in your vue Instance as shown below

```
data: () => ({
    column: true,
    mandatory: false,
    multiple: true,
```

Here is an [Example](https://codepen.io/elirehema-paul/pen/KKKRYaj?&editable=true&editors=101)